# 12 VDC power supply with automatic detection and switching

Tags: analog, power-electronics, switching

I am trying to run a solar system that will be used to power ~30 lights when the mains power is off. I'm running an AC-DC converter from the mains to get 12 V and this will power the lights when the power is up.

When the power cuts out, I want the solar battery to take over driving the lights automatically. I wanted to use an Arduino and implement the logic in that, but would rather use an analog approach.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could implement this? The lights will draw just under 30 A, and that's my biggest obstacle to overcome when building this. Any suggestions are welcome as I'm trying to explore different options.

Comment: How long, absolute worst case, do you expect to deliver 30 A at 12 V (360 Watts?)

Comment: Use a relay is my advice.

Comment: @periblepsis - worst case is 4 hours

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. Would a suitably rated relay be able to detect and switch the power supply efficiently and automatically?

Comment: How far will the battery be from the lights (i.e. what is the cable length)? For 30 A you would need fairly heavy cable.

Comment: @StarCat - all throughout a house, so relatively far away from the battery system, so yes re: heavy cable

Answer (score 1):

12V 30A, use an automotive headlight relay (typically these are good for up-to 40A loads).  Power the relay from the mains supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvsJku.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. My only issue would be that when the power goes off on mains, would the relay still be able to switch to the battery (solar) backup? Depending on how much power the relay uses, I'd want to run it off the battery system (I think) so that when the mains is off I can still have full control of the switching system.

Comment: the thing about relays is they are in one state with the power on, and when the power goes off they switch to the other state, so it will do what you want. there will be a short delay.